# Add row to database without having full table in DataSet?

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access

I've got a database hooked up to my VB.NET project and part of my program's operation is that I add a row to it. In the interests of efficiency, I'm trying to cut down on the data I'm pulling from the database. At the moment, I'm having to take the entire table (something I'd rather not do) I'd like to take as little data as possible in order to be able to add the row. Here's my current code:

```
MessagesDataSet.Clear()
MessagesTableAdapter.SelectCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Messages", MessagesTableAdapter.SelectCommand.Connection)
MessagesTableAdapter.Fill(MessagesDataSet)
Dim row As DataRow = MessagesDataSet.Tables(0).NewRow()
row.Item(0) = MessagesDataSet.Tables(0).Rows.Count + 1
row.Item(1) = uuid
row.Item(2) = Now
row.Item(3) = message
row.Item(4) = "<ROOM>"
row.Item(5) = currentRoomName
MessagesDataSet.Tables(0).Rows.Add(row)
MessagesTableAdapter.Update(MessagesDataSet)
```

If I try anything else I get an exception (usually that the row already belongs to the table, at the 2nd last line.) It's an Access (2007-2013) database with the first column (row.Item(0)) as the primary key.

Any help would be appreciated!

Update: I tried changing the SELECT statement to only pull down the primary key, but when I do that I get an IndexOutOfRangeException (Cannot find column 1) at the statement row.Item(1) = uuid.

Comment: Well your doing a select * thats why. Whats your condition to only pull back what you need? The only thing I see your actually using thats coming back is the row count.

Comment: you should not need any info at all from the DB to add a new row.

Comment: What @Plutonix said, plus consider using an identity (or auto-increment or whatever it's called in Access) field for your index. The code you have shown will crash if two users update the same table simultaneously - under race conditions they will potentially read the same rows.count and both attempt to insert a new row with the same index value. (I'm assuming your first field is a primary key)

Comment: It should also be noted that using RowCount to provide the ID will fail if you ever delete a row

Comment: @Codexer I tried narrowing down the SELECT statement to only include the row count (row.Item(0)). The trouble is, as soon as it hits the statement row.Item(1) = uuid, it tells me that it "Cannot find column 1".

Answer (score 0):

Change MessagesDataSet.Tables(0).Rows.Count + 1 to MessagesDataSet.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1

it will give you last row which you added recently